# Realm.init before or after migration

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a realm migration below that I run after the `Realm.init`. This seems to run okay. But when I get to the first function that uses realm I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Configurations cannot be different if used to open the same file. The most likely cause is that equals() and hashCode() are not overridden in the migration class: uk.Migrations
```

Now I am not sure how this is being caused or why, the code is very simple so shouldn't be causing that issue but yet it is, anything obvious that I am doing wrong here?

This only seems to take place AFTER an update takes place.

*MainActivity.java*

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Initialize Realm (just once per application)
    Realm.init(this);

    RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .schemaVersion(2) // Must be bumped when the schema changes
            .migration(new Migrations()) // Migration to run instead of throwing an exception
            .build();

    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
}
```

*Migrations.java*

```
public class Migrations implements RealmMigration{

    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {

        // DynamicRealm exposes an editable schema
        RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();

        Log.v("Realm", String.valueOf(oldVersion));

        if(oldVersion == 0){
            schema.get("Shipment")
                    .addField("scannedOut", Boolean.class);

            oldVersion++;
        }

        if(oldVersion == 1){
            schema.get("Shipment")
                    .addField("scannedIn", Boolean.class);

            oldVersion++;
        }
    }
}
```

First place Realm is used, where the error is triggered by the first line. This does take place after the migration is run.

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

realm.beginTransaction();
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(technician);
realm.commitTransaction();
```

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you are creating the same RealmConfiguration multiple times (as you are initializing Realm in the Activity instead of the Application), but the RealmConfigurations don't equal each other because you didn't implement equals/hashCode in provided configuration classes.

```
public class Migrations implements RealmMigration{
    ....

    @Override public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj != null && obj instanceof Migrations;
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        return Migrations.class.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Morning,

It actually turned out to be that we were hitting the main activity 2 times, putting the config code into an if statement checking if realm had been initiated solved the issue